# FileSystemWatcher on Threads

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Thanks for any help on this..

I am trying to write a little FileWatcher app that monitors a local directory and copies any changes across to another local directory. I have used the FileSystemWatcher class in .Net and on my btnStart click I run four threads, each with there own FileSysWatcher instance, watching for different change types. So the first i want to look for is the created event.

```
new Thread(Created).Start();
```

then i have:

```
void Created()
{
    FileSystemWatcher Watcher2 = new FileSystemWatcher();

    Watcher2.Path = txtBxDirToWatch.Text;
    Watcher2.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    //watch all files in the path 

    Watcher2.Filter = "*.*";

    //dont watch sub dir as default
    Watcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
    if (chkBxIncSub.Checked)
    {
        Watcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    }

    Watcher2.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
    Watcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

all I want this to do is copy any changes to a hard coded local path but I cant get any results. here is where I handled the event

```
public static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //combine new path into a string
    string created = Path.Combine(@"C:\WatcherChanges", e.Name);
    File.Create(created);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Does your OnCreated get hit then you create file? Are you sure e.Name is a file name, not a full file path?

Comment: Check if this new thread is ever created, Since you are accessing UI controls from new thread. I believe it is throwing exception and you are not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code thread finished and then GC collect and release Watcher.

Don't use thread for watchers or "hang" thread:

```
new Thread(Created){IsBackground = true}.Start(); 

void Created() 
{ 
  ...

  Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is exiting right after you tell the watcher to enable raising events. There is nothing in the `Create` method to keep the thread running. At the end of the `Create` method the `FileSystemWatcher` goes out of scope and the thread exits. It will never see any events.

There are a number of ways to get the thread to wait. Here is a simple one.

```
public class Watcher
{
    private ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public ManualResetEvent ResetEvent { get { return resetEvent; }

    void Created()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher Watcher2 = new FileSystemWatcher();

        Watcher2.Path = txtBxDirToWatch.Text;
        Watcher2.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        //watch all files in the path 

        Watcher2.Filter = "*.*";

        //dont watch sub dir as default
        Watcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        if (chkBxIncSub.Checked)
        {
            Watcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        }

        Watcher2.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        Watcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

Then change the method that calls `Thread.Start` to something like

```
Watcher watcher = new Watcher();
new Thread(watcher.Created).Start();
```

and when you want to stop watching

```
watcher.ResetEvent.Set();
```

Have you looked at [RoboCopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)? It will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to create the watchers in separate threads.

They will come back to you on [thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx) threads when something on your watched directory happens. When they do - you do your job on the thread pool thread if it's not UI related. If it is - you have to do [control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or post/send to the Gui thread using it's [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx).

And yes -as the others have already said - don't let your watchers get GC'd.